# IIS rewrite rule to redirect https to http not working

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

There's lots of questions here about redirecting http to https so I figured it would be easy to reverse the process. However, everything I've tried hasn't worked.

I'm trying to combine the rule with my canonical host name rule (it's the first rule, at the top of the rewrite rules):

```
<rule name="CanonicalHostName" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.example\.com|example-staging\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

The site is hosted on Azure and DNS is with CloudFlare if that makes any difference, I'm sure it shouldn't.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong / might be preventing the https to http part of the rule working? (the host name part works fine)

Comment: Is the app MVC? Do you maybe have a `RequireHttpsAttribute` either in the global filters or on a controller itself?

Comment: Yes, this is an MVC web application, but no RequireHttpsAttribute's anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CloudFlare

It seems the reason you cannot redirect away from SSL is because you are using CloudFlare. CloudFlare at a minimum uses flexible SSL. This means that the end user, browser shows the SSL lock but your server doesn't need SSL. See documentation here: https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl

Without CloudFlare the following example should work.

## No CloudFlare

The following rule should work. You could still add your negate in if you want.

```
<rule name="HTTPS to HTTP redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

---

Full rewrite section for my working demo site.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.ashleymedway\.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.ashleymedway.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="HTTPS to HTTP redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: @Gavin Odd, you must have something interfering with your setup, I have added the rule from my answer to https://www.ashleymedway.com and you can see the rule is working here.

Comment: thanks for the full example and having another go. My rules are basically identical to yours now now. Still the same issue. My site is www.topomap.co.nz - if you try preview.topomap.co.nz then the canonical rule works, but the https one never does. I wonder if it might be something to do with Azure or CloudFlare then? Very bizarre!

Comment: @Gavin Cloudflare requires https, see here https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl. See the section on flexible SSL

Comment: Thanks for that, just turned off Crypto - SSL (with SPDY) setting and the redirect works as expected now.

Comment: @Gavin brilliant, glad we got it sorted :)

Answer (score -1):

Your redirect is still **http**:

```
url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}"
```

You can follow these instructions: [Click Here](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/)

Additional information: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx)

Comment: That's correct - I want to force http, not https. Or am I missing something?